# Bool values conversion in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6

When I try to change the hidden value of a button with `performSelectorOnMainThread` this works:

```
[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:NO waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But this:

```
[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:YES waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Gives this error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an rvalue of type 'signed char'
```

What kind of internal conversion occurs to create this error? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Time to read a paper on (NULL) pointers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter is named `withObject:`. A BOOL isn't an object, but `nil` can be passed in, and `NO` is equivalent to it, so your first example works (by accident).

You have a few options, but the simplest is probably to use GCD and execute the setHidden: method in a block on the main thread instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the performSelector method you have to pass an object, as said in jrturton answer.
But...the BOOL type is not a primitive type

Here more informations about BOOL: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/564-bools-sharp-corners/

You can use this trick

```
[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];  // this is a setHidden:NO

[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];  // this is a setHidden:YES
```

I used self, but you can use any existing object. It will be TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this test:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", NO, @"b", nil];
NSLog("%@", array);
```

you will find that in the array there is only one object "a", which means the bool value `NO` is equal to `nil`. so in fact your worked code does like this

```
[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

which is acceptable.

actually, if you do this test:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"b", nil];
NSLog("%@", array);
```

you will find there are three objects in array: "a" "0" and "b".
so in your code, you should call like this:

```
[pictureButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES/NO] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Hope that helps!